# Pandas pivot table count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, pivot-table

I would like to ask a question concerning pivot tables in Pandas.
I have been trying to make a pivot table for this kind of table:

| sector | score |
| --- | --- |
| US | null |
| US | null |
| US | 1 |
| EU | null |
| EU | 2 |
| EU | 2 |
| EU | 4 |
| UK | null |
| UK | null |
| UK | null |
| UK | 4 |
| UK | 4 |

Eventually, I would like this table to be a pivot table that would look like this:

|  | null | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| EU | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| UK | 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

In order to do so, I have been trying to do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = sql("SELECT sector, score FROM database")

df_piv = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index = 'sector',
    columns = 'score',
    values = 'score',
    aggfunc = 'count'
)
```

However, by doing so, I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Could you please help me?
Thanks :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error btw, your code gives me an empty dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer using `groupby`, you can use

```
>>> df.groupby('sector')['score'].value_counts(dropna=False).unstack(fill_value=0)
score   NaN  1.0  2.0  4.0
sector                    
EU        1    0    2    1
UK        3    0    0    2
US        2    1    0    0
```

---

Sidenote:

If you did not want to count the missing values,

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='sector', columns='score', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

would do the trick. Using `len` as an actual function because for some reason `pivot_table`'s `aggfunc` parameter does not seem to accept string shortcuts like `groupby.agg`/`transform`.

Comment: Similar with crosstab but hacky to include nulls: `pd.crosstab(df['sector'],df['score'].fillna('NaN'))`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it worked!  I had another problem: I was not working with a Pandas DataFrame but a Spark DataFrame haha Thanks a lot!!